# drf-spectacular generate got multiple values for keyword argument 'context' error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-spectacular

Django 3.2/ DRF 3.14.0
When forming a page with api documentation, an error is observed in the console

```
got multiple values for keyword argument 'context'
```

Code sample

```
class CustomBatchView(mixin.ListModelMixin, mixin.CreateModelMixin, VendorViewSetMixin):
       def_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
            context = {'request': self.request}
            if self.action == 'create':
                return BatchCreateSerializer(*args, context=context, **kwargs)
            elif self.action in ['update', 'partial_update']:
                return BatchUpdateSerializer(*args, context=context, **kwargs)
            else:
                return BatchSerializer(*args, context=context, **kwargs)
```

The problem is that when Viewsets in DRF calls get_serializer, it passes context inside kwargs. So when I try to pass the context separately, there is a conflict.

The reason why I need separate context attribute is because using this logic further in

```
self.context.get('request')
```

So if implement this

```
    if 'context' in kwargs:
        del kwargs['context']
```

inside `get_serializer`

All work perfect.
Such a problem does not arise with business logic. Only at the moment of forming API documentation. What can this be related to and how can it be fixed?